# MYSQL - sum doesnt sum as intended

Tags: mysql, sum

It is 04.17 in the morning and i cant figure what is wrong! Help please!

I have table with such columns in table user_logs:

```
id | user_id | action | reference | time
----------------------------------------
1  |   1     | login  |     0     | 1333800404
2  |   1     | logout |     1     | 1333800424
3  |   1     | login  |     0     | 1333800434
4  |   1     | logout |     3     | 1333800444
```

And query:

```
SELECT reference r,
  sum(time-(SELECT time FROM users_logs WHERE id = r)) time_of_logon
FROM users_logs
WHERE user_id = 1 AND action = 'logout'
```

Unfortunately sum() function returns unexpected value.

If I remove sum() I get such a query:

```
SELECT reference r,
  (time-(SELECT time FROM users_logs WHERE id = r)) time_of_logon
FROM users_logs
WHERE user_id = 1 AND action = 'logout'
```

and result:

```
r | time_of_logon
-----------
1 | 20
3 | 10
```

As expected - i printed all rows with action 'logout' of user_id = 1 decrementing time of logoff from time i got from subquery (time of login connected with logout). Now i have time user was logged in. So far so good. Now, when I add sum (like in first query) I would expect sum of time_of_logon (should be 30). If I put avg function instead of sum i would expect 15 ((10+20)/2).

**Sum version:** I get 60,
**avg version** - i get 30.

Type of 'time' field is integer.

**My guessing:**
I guess that mysql somehow returns not 2 rows as it shows but it's working on 4 rows, or doubles some calculations beneath the main query. Because both - avg and sum result is twice as big as it should be.

Maybe it's the time issue that my brain is not working anymore but i cant figure out what is wrong. Please help.

Comment: That inner select looks awful. What are you trying to do and what is your expected result from the given table?

Comment: Can you explain what you want the query to Do? Guess time duration the user is logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, sum(time_of_logon) as sum_login_time
FROM
(
  SELECT user_id,
         reference as r, 
         (time-(SELECT time FROM users_logs WHERE id = r)) as time_of_logon
  FROM users_logs 
  WHERE user_id = 1 AND action = 'logout'
) subtable
GROUP BY user_id
```

can you do a two step query?

Comment: I could but i get error message: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias. I see it for the first time in my life

Answer (score 0):

Just use a normal join:

```
select t1.id as r, t2.time - t1.time as time_of_logon
from user_logs t1
join user_logs t2 on t2.reference = t1.id
where t1.action = 'login'
and t1.user_id = 1;
```

No need to join on anything other than what's shown, because only logouts have a non-zero reference value. Actually, `t1.action = 'login'` is not necessary either for the same reason, but can be left in - it might help performance a bit (you should test it)

This will perform pretty well too if you have an index on `reference`.

Comment: Unfortunatel your example doesnt work. there is no 'r2' or r1' table. even if i change it to t2 and t1 i get 'no field named r2' in query error. I like elegancy of example.

Comment: OK I fixed the typos. Let me know if it works for you now. Cheers