# Sum gave me wrong amount

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, sum

This is my table:

```
(Stuff Table)
id_stuff | prody_type | semester | amount_prod
   1        090            1          10
   2        210            2          35

(Amount Table)
id_amount | prod_type | semester | amount_stuff
     1       090             1           12
     2       210             2           15

(Product Table)
id_prod | type_prod | prod_number
   1       090          010
   2       210          020
```

And here's my code from my model file:

```
$this->db->select("sum(amount_stuff) as 'tot_amount_stuff'")
         ->from('stuff')
         ->join('product','prod_type=type_prod')      
         ->join('amount','stuff.prod_type=amount.prod_type')           
         ->WHERE('amount.semester', 2);
```

Then code to show in my page:

```
for each.......

<td><?php echo $row->tot_amount_stuf; ?></td>
```

And in my html page shows: *50* but that's wrong, the correct amount is ***15***

It's seems the 'sum' taking all from the tables '**Stuff**' and '**Amount**' on *semester 2*, but I only need to take/show the sum of amount_stuff from the Amount Table not from both tables.

I'm little bit confused here...Hope anyone can help me.

Best Regards,

Comment: Are you using MySQL? there's a known issue with Sum() in MySQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068374/mysql-sum-doesnt-sum-as-intended?rq=1

Comment: Are you certain that you are not taking the `SUM` of the `amount_prod` column from the `stuff` table?  This is the only way I can explain your observations.

Comment: `prody_type` is the colname in the table, but in the query you seem to be using `prod_type`

Comment: I'm sorry it's typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT sum(amount_stuff) as 'tot_amount_stuff'
FROM Amount
JOIN Stuff ON (Stuff.prody_type = Amount.prody_type)
JOIN product ON (Amount.prody_type = Product.type_prod)
WHERE amount.semester = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're referencing tables and columns in your select

```
$this->db->select("sum(amount.amount_stuff) as 'tot_amount_stuff'")
     ->from('stuff')
     ->join('product','prod_type=type_prod')      
     ->join('amount','stuff.prod_type=amount.prod_type')           
     ->WHERE('amount.semester', 2);
```

You'll want your SQL to render like so:

```
SELECT sum(amount.amount_stuff) as 'tot_amount_stuff'
FROM stuff
JOIN product ON (amount.prod_type = product.type_prod)
JOIN amount ON (stuff.prod_type = amount.prod_type)
WHERE amount.semester = '2'
```

You could also use aliases to shorten this process

```
SELECT sum(a.amount_stuff) as 'tot_amount_stuff'
FROM stuff s
JOIN product p ON (a.prod_type = p.type_prod)
JOIN amount a ON (s.prod_type = a.prod_type)
WHERE a.semester = '2'
```